# c do while loop doesn't work?

Tags: c

```
do
{
    printf("Enter number (0-6): ", "");
    scanf("%d", &Num);
}while(Num >= 0 && Num <=6);
```

any ideas?

Comment: How do you initialize the Num var?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also how/where was Num declared?

Comment: yes, same code as Mark Rushakoff

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: no errors - it repeats the loop if the number is between 0 and 6 for some reason

Comment: Also, the second argument to printf is redundant, and you need error checking on scanf.

Comment: If the number is between 0 and 6 your loop condition evaluates to true and will repeat until the condition is evaluated to false, i.e. a number greater than 6 or a number less than 0. Can you give us an example of what you were to expect?

Comment: Over time, you'll learn that "doesn't work" usually means "I am misunderstanding how it works".  More than 99% of the time, something not doing what you expected means that you were expecting the wrong thing, not that the software (in this case, the 'do-while loop in C') is broken.

Comment: Obligatory: Don't *ever* use `scanf`. http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: Hmm, no one noticed the second parameter to `printf` even though there are no format specifiers in the string? It probably has nothing to do with the issue, but it's another mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You're misunderstanding your loop.

Your code is read like this:

> Do *something* While (as long as) `num` is more than (or equal to) zero And `num` is less than (or equal to) six

The C compiler is listening to your code and doing exactly what you are (mistakenly) telling it to, which is to keep looping as long as the number is between 0 and 6.

You actually want it to keep looping as long as the number is *not* between 0 and 6, so you actually want the code to look like this:

> Do *something* While `num` is **less than** zero Or `num` is **more than** six

Once the user enters a number that *is* between 0 and 6, the code will see that `num` is neither less than 0 and nor more than 6, so it will stop the loop.  (Because the condition will be false)

You should be able to code that yourself.
Hints: `>` means 'more than', `<` means 'less than', and `||` means 'or'.

Comment: I can't believe I wrote that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It works completely fine for me, as long as `Num` is declared as an int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int Num;
    do
    {
    printf("Enter number (0-6): ", "");
    scanf("%d", &Num);
    } while(Num >= 0 && Num <=6);

    printf("Done.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Did you declare `Num` as a char, perhaps?

@tom: Here's a sample session with my compiled code; what's different when you run it?

```
$ gcc a.c && ./a.out
Enter number (0-6): 0
Enter number (0-6): 1
Enter number (0-6): 2
Enter number (0-6): 3
Enter number (0-6): 4
Enter number (0-6): 5
Enter number (0-6): 6
Enter number (0-6): 7
Done.
```

Comment: it seems to be repeating the code if the number is between 0 and 6 - but if i reverse the > to < then it still doesnt work :S

Comment: @tom: It's supposed to repeat as long as the number is between 0 and 6.

Comment: but even still, if i need to input something between 0 and 6, and I enter 90, it'll just skip the loop

Comment: @tom: that's how a (do) while loop is *defined* to work.  What's the behavior you *expect*?  The code is doing what you *told* it to do, but probably what you told it is not what you meant :)  That's probably the most common programming mistake, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add a `getchar` after `scanf` to remove '\n' from keyboard buffer:

```
do
{
    printf("Enter number (0-6): ", "");
    scanf("%d", &Num);
    getchar();
} while(Num >= 0 && Num <=6);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine with me, I have run your program, user can only enter the values from 0 to 6, do while work in this range, on other values loop break.